# Context aware nav menu in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to create an application with a navigation which is responsive to the content being shown. I have found an example which is part of the Aurelia docs themselves which would be perfect - unfortunately the code for the docs doesn't seem to be OSS.

I haven't been able to find any code examples, but I also don't know what to search for - is there a specific name for this UI pattern?

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the direction of a code example (preferably in Aurelia) or explain how I can achieve this functionality.

Please see the linked animated gif (can't embed images yet).
[Aurelia docs example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RvKM.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this particular case this component named "side-bar-view", it looks like composition of 2 lists + animation, so you can simply realize it by yourself (in another case - try to use solution from aurelia.io)